# Не могу открыть Activity по кнопке из Fragment (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment, activity

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  У меня есть Bottom Navigate, который вызывает фрагменты. Внутрь класса одного фрагмента добавил слушатель кнопки с фрагмента (в разметку фрагмента её добавил), который должен открыть мне необходимую activity. При нажатии на кнопку приложение падает.

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        OpenButtonProfile.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(activity, ProfileActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="ru.nowandroid.youtube.nowjsoupandroid">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <activity android:name=".HomeProfileActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".NewsActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: приложите текст ошибки из логов, пожалуйста!

Comment: У вас инициализирована activity?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov В Manifest вроде всё добавлено

Comment: @Circassian    В манифест добавлено

Comment: Добавляйте манифест тогда) Ошибка-то на него указывает...

Comment: @NobodyKnows нет, я имею в виду переменную, которую вы передаете в качестве контекста здесь Intent(activity, ProfileActivity::class.java)

Comment: @Circassian в `onViewCreated` гарантируется, что она инициализирована

Comment: @Circassian    Нет, не добавлял. Нужно её инициализировать в классе вне функций intent Intent =

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо добавить вашу ProfileActivity в Манифест.

Вот пример:

```
<manifest . . . >
    <permission android:name="com.example.project.DEBIT_ACCT" . . . />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.project.DEBIT_ACCT" />
    . . .
    <application . . .>
        <activity android:name="com.example.project.FreneticActivity"
                  android:permission="com.example.project.DEBIT_ACCT"
                  . . . >
            . . .
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Рекомендую вам почитать [документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro?hl=ru) о том как использовать манифест.

Comment: Спасибо, не видел ответ, но я так и сделал. Работает!